# Как получать результат работы сервера с некоторым интервалом?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть код:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        let time = new Date();
        time = moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY, k:m:s');
        console.log(time);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Через каждые 1000 милисекунд он выводит время в консоль. Но как сделать, чтобы пользователь мог сам задать время вывода времени в консоль. Я нашёл что-то похожее на то, что мне нужно, но не понимаю, как можно передать параметр из консоли в код:

> $ node server.js -i [console output recurrence interval] -t [time
> after which the web client message will be displayed]

Если я введу к примеру такой код:

> $ node server.js -i 500 -t 2500

То ничего не изменится, т.к в `setInterval()` осталась та же 1000.
Как можно получить значения из консоли ввода?

Comment: Непонятно какое отношение http-сервер имеет к выводу в консоль.

Comment: Параметры командной строки лежат в [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv) и для этого есть [куча пакетов](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Aargv%20keywords%3Aargs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже было сказано в коментариях - параметры командной строки лежат в `process.argv`.
Поэтому проблему решил вот так:

```
let args = process.argv;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        let time = new Date();
        time = moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY, k:m:s');
        console.log(time);
    }, args[3]);
});
```